# How to return a value from an Object Literal based on a key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array as follows. How would I retrieve the value of a specific key and put that value in a variable?

```
var obj = {"one":"1","two":"3","three":"5","four":"1","five":"6"};
```

So for instance if I want to get the value of "three" how would I do it in javascript or jQuery?

Comment: That's not an array; that's an object literal.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this via [dot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation) or [bracket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) notation, like this:

```
var myVariable = obj.three;
//or:
var myVariable = obj["three"];
```

In the second example `"three"` could be a string in another variable, which is *probably* what you're after.  Also, for clarity what you have is just an object, not an array :)

Comment: may I ask you a side question? Lets say the key that I want to look for is a variable. Would it be this var mmyVariable = obj[key_that_I_am_looking_for];

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution (by the way this is an object not an array):

```
var obj = {"one":"1","two":"3","three":"5","four":"1","five":"6"};
var myFunc = function(thisObj, property) {console.log(obj[property])};
myFunc(obj, "two");
//Output will be 3
```

You can also do this more easily using the `_.pluck` function from the Underscore JS library.