# Populate tooltip with JSON based on element data-tooltip value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Just looking for some advice or documentation on the following if possible(not looking for someone to do this for me, I just can't seem to find anything pertinent to what I want to do).

I want to populate a tooltip popup with data based on the hovered elements data-tooltip value. I've found how to populate tooltips with JSON, but not how to check the element first for a common value and search the JSON for that same value and THEN populate the tooltip.

So for instance, below you will see I have 3 separate `<div>`'s with different data-tooltip values. What I would like to do is when hovered, the tooltip would then populate with JSON from the json object named the same as the data-tooltip value.

To be clear, I understand HOW to populate divs with JSON data, but I don't know how to search JSON data based on data within the element(such as the elements data-tooltip value).

ex. If elements data-tooltip value = "skill-one", how can I then populate the tooltip with the JSON from the "skill-one" object? Or how can I write the JS to compare the two?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm looking to learn how to do this not looking for someone to do this for me. I've been researching for hours and haven't gotten very far.

```js
tooltipData = {
    "skill-one": {
        "value1":"skill-one value1",
        "value2":"skill-one value2",
        "value3":"skill-one value3"
    },
    "trinket-two": {
        "value1":"trinket-two value1",
        "value2":"trinket-two value2",
        "value3":"trinket-two value3"
    },
 }

$('.skill, .trinket, .hero').hover(
  function() { 
    console.log( 'hovering on' , $(this).attr('tooltip') ); 

    var tooltip = $("<div class='tooltip'>test</div>")
    .css({
      'color': '#fff',
      'position': 'absolute',
      'zIndex': '99999',
      'width': '100px',
      'height': '150px',
      'background-color': '#333',
    });
    $(this).append(tooltip);
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
      $('.tooltip').css({
        left:  e.pageX+10,
        top:   e.pageY-10
      });
    });
  },
  function() {
   $('.tooltip').remove();
  }
);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='skill' data-tooltip="skill-one">Skill One</div>
<div class='trinket' data-tooltip="trinket-two">Trinket Two</div>
<div class='hero' data-tooltip="hero-three">Hero Vestal</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a `data` property in jQuery use the function `data(name)`. In your case instead of `$(this).attr('tooltip')` --> `$(this).data('tooltip')`. You can also access the data object with `attr` but you need to use the full property name: `$(this).attr('data-tooltip')`.

> The above in retrospect is not the answer to the OP's question, but in light of the posted code relevant.

The real solution is this part:

```
var tooltipJSON = tooltipData[$(this).data("tooltip")];
var tooltipValues = [];

if (tooltipJSON) {
  $.each(tooltipJSON, function(key, value) {
    tooltipValues.push(key + ":" + value);
  });
}
```

It gets the correct object from the javascript object `tooltipData` using the `data` object. After that it uses `$.each` to iterate over all values putting them in a new array. After that use `join` to put the values into the tooltip.

```js
tooltipData = {
  "skill-one": {
    "value1": "skill-one value1",
    "value2": "skill-one value2",
    "value3": "skill-one value3"
  },
  "trinket-two": {
    "value1": "trinket-two value1",
    "value2": "trinket-two value2",
    "value3": "trinket-two value3"
  },
}

$('.skill, .trinket, .hero').hover(
  function() {
    //console.log( 'hovering on' , $(this).attr('tooltip') ); 
    var tooltipJSON = tooltipData[$(this).data("tooltip")];
    var tooltipValues = [];
    
    if (tooltipJSON) {
      $.each(tooltipJSON, function(key, value) {
        tooltipValues.push(key + ":" + value);
      });
    }

    var tooltip = $("<div class='tooltip'>" + tooltipValues.join("<br>") + "</div>")
      .css({
        'color': '#fff',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'zIndex': '99999',
        'width': '100px',
        'height': '150px',
        'background-color': '#333',
      });
    $(this).append(tooltip);
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
      $('.tooltip').css({
        left: e.pageX + 10,
        top: e.pageY - 10
      });
    });
  },
  function() {
    $('.tooltip').remove();
  }
);
```

```css
divd {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='skill' data-tooltip="skill-one">Skill One</div>
<div class='trinket' data-tooltip="trinket-two">Trinket Two</div>
<div class='hero' data-tooltip="hero-three">Hero Vestal</div>
```

Comment: Whoops sorry. I had at first thought this was the solution, my apologies. What I was interested in was how to pull the JSON data based on the data-tooltip value. So If the data-tooltip value = skill-one, how can I then search through the JSON for an object also named skill-one and then filter through results as needed?

Comment: I just had `var tooltip = $("<div class='tooltip'>test</div>")` as a filler just to show the popup. Ultimately I will build a better template to show each individual value of the JSON object. I just need to know how to populate that based on the data-tooltip value.

Comment: Done deal man. You're a pro! Thanks for the help and very informational.

Comment: Sorry man, one last question if you don't mind. How can I call the specific values within the array? I tried the following with no luck. I tried `tooltipValues.value1` instead of `tooltipValues.join` thinking it would pull the value1 for the object because that's how I have done it in the past?

Comment: Nevermind, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113083/return-value-in-array-of-specific-key-value-pair. Thanks again for the help!